# How can I debug a process started from another process?

Tags: debugging, process, process.start

I have a hub application that is responsible for handling the launching of three other programs. I am having considerable difficulty with this - When I launch one of the three alone, everything is fine; when I try to run them from the main hub application, they crash.

I need to figure out how I can keep the hub open, and open the process I start with the debugger after it launches right off, so I can catch the issues and debug it properly.

To give an example for how I am starting the processes from the main program -

```
this.Hide( );
Process.Start( FilePath).WaitForExit( );
Process.GetCurrentProcess( ).Kill( );
```

Comment: What's the tool you're using to run the processes? Is it from an IDE, the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a setup that allows it to debug any application that crashes before calling ExitProcess() and in case the process threw an exception, if the exception is not caught (i.e. try + catch(...) + exit(1)).

I always let the installer turn on that feature, but if you have it turned off, you should be able to turn it back on by going in the settings. Once one, on a crash, you get a message box asking you whether you want to debug the crashing process.